# No Banshee notification area icon in Gnome 3 classic session

Tags: banshee, icons, notification-area, gnome-classic

After installing Ubuntu 12.04, I have a problem with Banshee: it doesn't have a tray icon. I know about the tray-icon-plugin, but it's not working:

[image]

I'm using Gnome 3 in classic mode. In gnome-shell Banshee has an icon. How can I get the tray-icon to work in a classic session?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

You can add the notification applet to the gnome-panel as shown in the picture.

To add, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> and right-click the gnome-panel to add the notification applet.

However, banshee is fully integrated in the sound-indicator, to perhaps the use of the notification icon is not required.

[image]

Comment: Thx. Before I was think, that this applet already installed, because skype had icon. Now all right, banshee has icon too.

Comment: it's curious, not work for me (ubuntu 13.04). i'm interesting to show "add to panel" windows; how to?

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you for putting the effort in to post clear and concise instructions!

Comment: One more thing, Once adding the Notification panel, one might want to restart their apps so that they succesfully register their app icons to be shown in Notification. This worked for me for skype. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install package: **banshee-extension-appindicator**

```
sudo apt-get install banshee-extension-appindicator
```

This package provides integration for Banshee with Application Indicators,
which is a replacement for the notification area in Ubuntu, as a way to add
menus in the panel.

**REMEMBER to enable it as extension from  banshee's preferences.**

Answer (score 1):

Open Banshee UI. Go to Menu **Edit > Preferences > Extensions**.

There are several groups like communityExtensions,ContextPane...

Go to **Utilies** group. **Notification Area** **sound Menu integration** are the required options.

On my laptop these 2 options are exclusive. **Notification Area** gives a banshee icon in notification area. But has only one option to seek the play bar by hovering the mouse over the icon.

All other options are present in the menu on left click.