# Some system tray icons invisible in Gnome Classic 12.04

Tags: 12.04, indicator, notification, gnome-classic, system-tray

Tried all possible ways to give visibility to tray icons in Ubuntu 12.04 but no luck :(

- Dconf-editor -> Navigate to Desktop -> Unity -> Panel -> change the value of systray-whitelist to "all"
- gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
- Set values of above to include pidgin, davmail, etc.

Please note that only some tray icons are invisible. I still cant see pidgin, davmail, guake tray icons. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome classic mode (gnome-session-fallback).

Comment: I probably see a mistake here: dconf-editor is for unity. gnome classic probably uses the old gconf so you need gconf-editor (will remove if wrong assumption).

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Ambiance and Radiance themes. Try Adwaita.

Comment: If this is due to a bug, it would be good to [report it as one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Some related questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343788/skype-nofitication-icon-on-gnome-session-fallback-12-04 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/166267/why-doesnt-cryptkeeper-work-in-12-04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to add the `Notification Area` applet.
Taken from this question [No Banshee notification area icon in Gnome 3 classic session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121426/no-banshee-notification-area-icon-in-gnome-3-classic-session)

Comment: Thanks Vangop, that solved it. I was under the impression that indicator-applet-complete should handle this. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you plz mark it as answered then.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this also works for the missing tray icon of Shutter.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem with davMail on xubuntu using the following method:-

1. Open the task manager and if davmail is running, kill it.
2. Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk`.
3. Re-start DavMail and you should see the icon in the notification area.

It took me along time to find the solution, but it is quick and simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the indicator applets to your panel? This might help: [I can't add a Indicator Applet to Panel in Gnome-Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69377/i-cant-add-a-indicator-applet-to-panel-in-gnome-classic)

Comment: Yes, like in one of the comment in the link you mentioned, in 12.04, it is used by default in gnome-session-fallback. I have many tray icons, but there are some which do not seem to be visible like Pidgin, Davmail, etc.

Comment: With pidgin, you can go to the preferences and set Show tray icon to Always. I guess the other apps have similar settings as they would otherwise use the indicator applets.