# Skype Nofitication Icon on Gnome Session Fallback (12.04)

Tags: skype, panel, gnome-classic, gnome-session

I have the Ubuntu 12.04.2 installed on my machine. I also have Skype 4.2.0.11 installed. Skype icon won't appear on the notification panel (upper right). I can't see a way to get it working.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: type the following command in terminal `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`

Comment: That worked. post it as an answer so I can choose it as the right one =)

Comment: Glad to know. Done :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the following package

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

type the following

`sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`